# How to use AFNetwowrking2.0 code for this Example url?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, afnetworking-2

Hi I have one example url Which returns JSON Format. but when i use AFNetWorking2.0 to get the response from that URL, i am not getting correct Response. Here i am sending my code also.

```
- (void)testHTTPS {
  AFSecurityPolicy *securityPolicy = [[AFSecurityPolicy alloc] init];
  [securityPolicy setAllowInvalidCertificates:YES];
   AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
//manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
  [manager setSecurityPolicy:securityPolicy];

  [manager GET:@"xxxxx"
     parameters:nil
     success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
         NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
         NSString* newStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
         NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject options:kNilOptions error:nil];
     } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
         NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
     }];
}
```

I am getting JSON Dic always nil. and if i print "newstr" i am getting html format response. can anyone please find correct way?

I have done as you said John but i am getting the below result

> Error: Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1016 "Request failed: unacceptable content-type: text/html" UserInfo=0x7ffb39c52ed0 {com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.response= { URL: xxxxx } { status code: 200, headers {
>       "Cache-Control" = "public, max-age=10800";
>       "Content-Encoding" = gzip;
>       "Content-Length" = 2922;
>       "Content-Type" = "text/html";
>       Date = "Wed, 29 Apr 2015 06:49:54 GMT";
>       Expires = "Wed, 29 Apr 2015 09:49:55 GMT";
>       "Last-Modified" = "Wed, 01 Apr 2015 03:19:39 GMT";
>       Server = "ECAcc (hhp/9ABE)";
>       Vary = "Accept-Encoding";
>       "X-Cache" = HIT;
>   } }, NSErrorFailingURLKey=xxxxx, com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.data=<0d0a3c21 444f4354 59504520 68746d6c 20505542 4c494320 222d2f2f 5733432f 2f445444 20584854 4d4c2031 2e302054 72616e73 6974696f 6e616c2f 2f454e22 20226874 74703a2f 2f777777 2e77332e 6f72672f 54522f78 68746d6c 312f4454 442f7868 746d6c31 2d747261 6e736974 696f6e61 6c2e6474 64223e0d 0a3c6874 6d6c2078 6d6c6e73 3d226874 74703a2f 2f777777 2e77332e 6f72672f 31393939 2f786874 6d6c223e 0d0a3c68 6561643e 0d0a3c6d 65746120 68747470 2d657175 69763d22 436f6e74 656e742d 54797065 2220636f 6e74656e >, NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: unacceptable content-type: text/html}

Comment: it seems the response is not JSON, but XML/HTML (see `Content-Type`), you may need to consider to set up the proper response serializer for that.

Comment: especially the response is: `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">  <head>  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" conten`

Comment: Hi holex... but if i past that link in onlinejsonviewer it is showing JSON format result.

if i past that link in search bar then also iam getting JSON result

Comment: I would recommend to take a look on that URL which shows you the [headers properly](http://apikitchen.com/#pts0B), and that says the `Content-Type: text/html`, not JSON – the visual look of the content is not really relevant here, I'm afraid.

Comment: **PLUS:** on mobile devices the original link has been redirected to a mobile HTML website: http://m.raaga.com/redis/facade.php?svc=home-mobile&l=T, which is definitely an HTML page; your original link looks working in desktop browsers only.

Comment: ok...thanks holex.thanks for your suggesion.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're using the `AFHTTPResponseSerializer` rather than AFNetworking's `AFJSONResponseSerializer`. Therefore, when the response comes in, it is parsing it as a HTTP response rather than a JSON response. This is easily fixed by assigning your `manager.responseSerializer` to `AFJSONResponseSerializer` instead:

```
manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
```

You'll find that you won't need to create an NSDictionary from the response - upon success it should come through as an `NSDictionary` object already.

Check out the [**AFNetworking 2.0 migration guide**](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/wiki/AFNetworking-2.0-Migration-Guide). It's a very handy read and will make you aware of what to look out for in the future.

Comment: thanks john Rogers. i will check this evening as you said. and i will update you result.

Comment: I have done as you said John but i am getting the Error. I have edited my post by adding that error.

Comment: That error is because your web service is returning a content type of "text/html" rather than "application/json". The serialiser requires this content type header to be like so. You're going to have to figure out how to serialise the JSON from the response using a HTTP serialiser if you can't change the content type header of your web service.